# Is Reselect really needed in the Todo List example in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I am looking ways to improve performance of my React application. After some searching, I look into Reselect. But I am not sure how the [example](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#example) works.

In the example, it states that `todos` is calculated every time the component is updated which hurts performance. So it introduces the use of memoized selector to overcome it.

Will there be difference if I put `getVisibleTodos` in the component `render` function? What am I thinking to do is like:

`containers/VisibleTodoList.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleTodo } from '../actions'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
      return todos
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
  }
}

/*const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}*/

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: state.todos,
    visibilityFilter: state.visibilityFilter
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = ({todos, visibilityFilter, ...props}) => {
  const visibleTodos = getVisibleTodos(todos, visibilityFilter);
  return (
    <TodoList todos={visibleTodos} {...props} />
  )
}

const ConnectedVisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(VisibleTodoList)

export default ConnectedVisibleTodoList
```

In this case, `getVisibleTodos` won't be called unless `todos` or `visibilityFilter` change. Right? Does my modification do the same as the selectors do? Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't optimise something you cannot measure.

Comment: @zerkms I think that's why he is asking for help.

Comment: @RafaelBerro I don't think so, they ask for a general advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `getVisibleTodos` will still be called and will re-calculate when `VisibleTodoList` re-renders.

<del>Besides, since `VisibleTodoList` is a functional component, it will be re-rendered every single time when its parent component has an update.

So no, your code and Reselect behave differently. I guess what you want is a class component, and add `shouldComponentUpdate` to compare `todos` and `visibilityFilter` manually, then you can avoid unnecessary calculations.</del>

`VisibleTodoList` is wrapped by `connect` of react-redux, and react-redux has already provided a `shouldComponentUpdate` for you.

But even if you use `shouldComponentUpdate` or `connect`, it's still not as optimized as Reselect. Because when you switch between All, Active or Completed tabs, `getVisibleTodos` will be called and there will be a lot of duplicated re-calculations. (Reselect caches these results, so there is no duplicated re-calculation)

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I wonder if `VisibleTodoList` will really be re-rendered every single time when its parent component has an update. 

As I know, component wrapped in `connect` will check for any state/props changes before re-render. It makes me think about the point/advantage of using Reselect if such checking is already present.

Comment: Yes you are right. There are some optimizations in `react-redux`

Comment: In that example, one of the input selector is `getVisibilityFilter`. So I think even with the use of selector, the component will get re-rendered if switches between those tabs

Comment: Yes of course the component will be re-rendered. But the point of Reselect is memoization. It caches the result of `getVisibilityFilter` so it doesn't need to do `todos.filter(...)` every single time